# Keep session between 2 retrofit instances

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp

In my application, I would like to abstract requests to my API. However, to access my API, the user needs to log in and the server sends back a cookie in the form of a JSESSIONID.

So I have a first Retrofit instance created for this using an interface containing the methods for the user to log in :

```
interface MyService {
    @POST("api/login" )
    fun login(@Header("cred")id: String): Completable

    companion object {
        operator fun invoke(): MyService {
            val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

            val cookieHandler = CookieManager()

            val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().addNetworkInterceptor(interceptor)
                .cookieJar(JavaNetCookieJar(cookieHandler))
                .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build()

            return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://mytestapi.com")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build()
                .create(MyService::class.java)
    }
}
```

I would like to create a second Retrofit interface that allows me to make very specific queries, but to do so, the user must be logged in.

How can I pass the `MyService` login token to my second Retrofit?

Comment: Store the login token to sharedPrefs and instantiate the second retrofit using the token from prefs

Comment: How can I get this login token via my Retrofit instance ?